# NameError: name 'ObjectNotExist' is not defined

Tags: django, django-views

The following error occurs when converting HTML to PDF:

> NameError: name 'ObjectNotExist' is not defined

views.py:

```
def cart(request, total=0, quantity=0, cart_item=None):

    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, is_active=True)
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
            quantity += cart_item.quantity

    except ObjectNotExist:
        # 'ObjectDoesNotExist'
        pass

    context = {
        'total': total,
        'quantity': quantity,
        'cart_items': cart_items,
    }

    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
```

Comment: Spelling error.  The correct exception name is `ObjectDoesNotExist`.

Answer (score 1):

You use `Model.DoesNotExist` with *`Model`* the one for which we query that might not return anything, or `ObjectDoesNotExist`. The former is more specific and therefore often a better idea:

```
def cart(request, total=0, quantity=0, cart_item=None):
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, is_active=True)
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity
            quantity += cart_item.quantity

    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        total = quantity = cart_items = None

    context = {
        'total': total,
        'quantity': quantity,
        'cart_items': cart_items,
    }
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)
```